# Modify permanently a CSS of a website that I do not own, and distribute the change to my network

Tags: css, customization

What is the easiest way to do it?

I have difficulties to understand and not having now enough time to spend and study Greasemonkey properly, to just apply a PERMANENT css change to ANY website.

I thought that was more easy, to just add a CSS that would stay with the browser. But I do not find any easy/quick tool customization to just add a simple .css file to do my changes.

For example I would like to restyle Twitter, because I hate the new design, It is killing any kind of graphic personalization that I would like to have.

I need it simple, because I want to let people with not high tech knowledge, to be able to get my personalization, implement it and do it as well.

I know that this could have a security issue, but all that I want to do it is add a piece of CSS, and not additional Javascript functionality.

EDIT: Possibly that could work in all the browsers, not only Chrome and Firefox (I know that might not exist, but I would like to have an alternative for people that use IE)

I am an expert web designer, but I am not a programmer. Outside Javascript I do not script anything else.

Comment: Interpretation - "Plz gives me teh codez"

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand. What is the problem? I looked for an answer, but I do not find any decent thing after googling a while, without have to study a programmatic language for various hours. I am a web designer, but I am not an expert programmer, I do need an easy solution because even people that are not programmer should be able to implement it.

Comment: @myles: there's plenty of legit reasons for wanting to override a stylesheet, low vision users spring immediately to mind.

Comment: @Littlemad - It doesn't take much to do [this](http://tinyurl.com/5va6op7)

Comment: @Gordon - I wasn't criticising WHY he wants to do it but the fact he didn't Google the problem which with any degree of knowledge of what he wanted to do would have been easy to find: http://tinyurl.com/5va6op7

Comment: Myles you are assuming wrongly, and I am sorry to say you are just being rude. I did google it, and end up on the page of Stylish, but the webpage looked ugly and old style. I didn't trust to install a plugin that I wasn't sure that the source was a reliable one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). Make custom CSS file. Winning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it there an alternative solution for IE? This is a partial solution.

Comment: In this case you want to install a tool like Charles and map the resource to your local CSS. This will always return the CSS file instead of the one on the server.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [Stylish extension](http://userstyles.org/stylish/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it there an alternative solution for IE? This is a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a user stylesheet in several major browsers that will override the site stylesheet.  It will require a good working knowledge of CSS though and for firefox you have to create the file manually in your profile.

http://www.squarefree.com/userstyles/user-style-sheets.html